# ggplot change y axis numeric values to text

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels

I created this barplot:

[image]

with this code

```
ggplot(bp, aes(x = labels, y = V2)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", fill="#003560")+
  xlab("Bedtime Procrastination Items")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,5))+
  ylab(NULL)
```

Now I want to change the labels of the y-axis. Instead of 1-5 it should be: "never", "almost never" "sometimes", "frequently", "always".

I tried some approaches like creating an object with the labels (see below), but I guess it did not work since it's a numeric variable.
I can't change it to a character, because then my y-axis would not have the range from 1 to 5 anymore.

```
yaxis <- c("never", "almost never", "sometimes", "frequently", "always")
scale_y_discrete(labels = yaxis)
```

Comment: You could probably set `scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:5, labels = yaxis)`.

Comment: perfect, that works! Thank you very much! Don't know why I didn't try this